# How do I make an "if and if" statement in Windows Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

This one is more of a curiosity question, but is there a way in Windows Batch to be able to make an `if file.ext exists && if file2.ext exists (echo Yes.) else (echo No.)` -type command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can implement AND/OR operator like:

```
if exist file1.ext (
  if exist file2.ext (
    echo Yes, both file1.ext and file2.ext exist
  ) else (
    echo No, both file1.ext and file2.ext not exist
  )
) else (
  If exist file2.ext (
    echo file1.ext does NOT exist but file2.ext does exist
  )
)
```

To check if File2.ext does exist and file1.ext not exist then:

```
if exist file1.ext (
  if not exist file2.ext (
     echo file1.ext does exist but file2.ext does NOT exist
  )
)
```

**Placement of the Else keywords matter!**

Read more:

- [Boolean logic in batch files - Rob Van Der Woude's Scripting pages](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_booleanlogic.php)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `if` to check if your files exist:

**1.** Replace `if exist && file1 if exist file2` to `dir /w file1 file2`

```all-bat
dir /w file1.ext file2.ext
```

- **Obs.: 1** Outputs:

[image]

**2.** Suppress any possible errors if any or both files do not exist and redirect the output of the command `dir` to `findstr`

```all-bat
2>nul dir /w file1.ext file2.ext | findstr /i "file1.ext.*file2.ext" ...
```

- **Obs.: 2** Suppress any possible errors using **`2>nul`** and redirect the output with **`|`**

**3.** Use operator:

- `findstr &&` to handle `return 0` both file1.ext and file2.ext exist
- `findstr ||` to handle `return non 0` file1.ext or file2.ext (or both) not exist

```all-bat
2>nul dir /w file1.ext file2.ext | findstr /i "file1.ext.*file2.ext" && echo\yEp! || echo\nOp!
```

---

- **Obs.: 3** In `findstr` not to be case-sensitive (capital letters | lower case), use `/i`, as the string has some spaces between filenames on the same line, use `.` um or more `*` characters

```all-bat
... | findstr /i "file1.ext.*file2.ext" && ...
```

---

- Possible Cases/Outputs from `findstr` returns:

```all-bat
:: Exist file1.ext == True
:: Exist file2.ext == True
:: Results => Return "0" == echo\yEp!

:: Exist file1.ext == False
:: Exist file2.ext == False
:: Results => Return non "0" == echo\nOp!

:: Exist file1.ext == True
:: Exist file2.ext == False
:: Results => Return non "0" == echo\nOp!

:: Exist file1.ext == False
:: Exist file2.ext == True
:: Results => Return non "0" == echo\nOp!
```

---

You can also use a `for` loop to do the same when multiple files need to be checked and what to import is one does not exist, in which case you can immediately move batch processing to a `:label` when this condition is met, if all files exist, subsequent/following lines will be executed.

```all-bat
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0"
for %%i in ("file1.ext","file2.ext","file3.ext","file4.ext","file5.ext"
)do if not exist "%%~i" echo\File "%%~i" does Not exist && goto %:^( 

:: Run more commands below, because all your files exist...

goto=:EOF 

%:^(
:: Run more commands below, because one some of your files don't exist

goto=:EOF
```

- **Obs.: 4** After the relevant executions after the `for`loop or inside the label `%:^(`, use `goto=:EOF` to move the processing to the **E**nd **O**f **F**ile or to another `:label` if applicable...

```all-bat
:: Run more commands below, because all your files exist...

goto=:EOF

%:^(
:: Run more commands below, because one some of your files don't exist

goto=:EOF
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Dir /?](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)**

  [√] **[Findstr /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Redirections in bat file](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**